# How to set flutter version in snapcraft.yaml?

Tags: linux, flutter, snapcraft, multipass

My application is developed based on flutter3.3.10 version.
I build and publish it as a Linux application to the Snap Store, but using the snapcraft command will automatically download the latest version of flutter.
How do I set the flutter version?

```html
name: step-print # you probably want to 'snapcraft register <name>'
base: core18 # the base snap is the execution environment for this snap
version: '1.0' # just for humans, typically '1.2+git' or '1.3.2'
summary: Make printing easier # 79 char long summary
icon: snap/gui/step-print.png
description: |
  This is my-snap's description. You have a paragraph or two to tell the
  most important story about your snap. Keep it under 100 words though,
  we live in tweetspace and your description wants to look good in the snap
  store.

grade: stable # must be 'stable' to release into candidate/stable channels
confinement: strict # use 'strict' once you have the right plugs and slots

slots:
  dbus-step-print: # adjust accordingly to your app name
    interface: dbus
    bus: session
    name: org.bar.step_print # adjust accordingly to your app name and

apps:
  step-print:
    command: step_print
    extensions: [flutter-stable] # Where "master" defines which Flutter channel to use for the build
    plugs:
      - network
      - home
      - desktop
    slots:
      - dbus-step-print

parts:
  step-print:
    source: .
    plugin: flutter
    flutter-target: lib/main.dart # The main entry-point file of the application
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this :-

```
  super-cool-app:
    command: super_cool_app
    extensions: [flutter-stable] <'put version here'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but this doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: This is my example:
step-print:
     command: step_print
     extensions: [flutter-stable] < 'v3.3.10'
or
     extensions: [flutter-stable] < '3.3.10'

Comment: Here is the error message:
snapcraft.yaml parsing error: while parsing a block mapping
   in "snap/snapcraft.yaml", line 23, column 5
expected <block end>, but found '<scalar>'
   in "snap/snapcraft.yaml", line 24, column 34